# iOS - Property 'isConnected' not found on object of type 'CBPeripheral'

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to replicate an Android App I already made to iOS. I'm trying to make a BLE application where my iOS Device would be able to see and connect to BLE Devices and get the RSSI (I really don't care about the message and other data). Upon a search research, I found [this BLTE Central Peripheral Transfer Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927)in the iOS Developer Library. Upon downloading, opening the XCode Project, and then ran it. However, I ran into an error shorty after with this code:

```
if (!self.discoveredPeripheral.isConnected) {
    return;
}
```

where the error is: `Property 'isConnected' not found on object of type 'CBPeripheral'`

Upon searching again, [I found this link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5941). However, it seems that the thread does not have any solutions as the answers discussed also seem to be deprecated. I can't seem to find any solutions for this issue as well.

Has anyone tried to make the code from the iOS developer library work?

Answer (score 7):

The documentation says

> Deprecation Statement
>   Use the **state** property instead.

Comment: call state property as below
if (self.discoveredPeripheral.state != CBPeripheralStateConnected) {
    return; // not connected
}

Answer (score 4):

`isConnected` has been deprecated, try this code instead

```
if (self.discoveredPeripheral.state != CBPeripheralStateConnected) {
    return;
}
```